# How to see changelists without version control

Tags: version-control, pycharm, ide, jetbrains-ide, changelist

I am in PyCharm, working for now on a project without version control. But I find changelist handling very useful... the problem is that changelists are linked to VCS.

It exists some way to use "local changelists", only for local modifications, in the same way as classical?

Comment: Consider using `Local History` https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/local-history.html

Comment: There are no changelists for local history.